# How to remove all numbers, but keep the ordinals?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following string:

```
Friday the 13th (1980)
```

Now I'd like to remove "1980" from the string, and not the "13" using C# Regex. So that it looks like below:

```
Friday the 13th ()
```

Basically I want to remove all numbers in a string except for the ones that are followed by "st", "nd", "rd", "th". e.g., 13th, 1st, 23rd etc.

I was able to remove all numbers with the following regex:

```
Regex.Replace("Friday the 13th (1980)", @"\d+", string.Empty);
```

But can't figure out how I can keep the ones followed by "st", "nd", "rd" or "th".

Thanks.

Comment: Read [the documentation section on "negative lookahead assertion"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookahead_assertion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookahead_assertion), like this:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\d+(?!\d|th|st|rd|nd)", "");
```

Comment: Is the closing square bracket ']' necessary in the expression?

Comment: @kayes: No it isn't, thanks for spotting that (was a cut+paste artifact)

Answer (score 2):

I would use a negative lookahead and some word boundaries for the specific things you mentioned:

```
Regex.Replace("Friday the 13th (1980)",@"\b\d+\b(?!(?:st|[nr]d|th))",string.Empty);
```

But perhaps a simple word boundary would work, depending on what you're trying to do:

```
Regex.Replace("Friday the 13th (1980)",@"\b\d+\b",string.Empty);
```

`(?! ... )` is a negative lookahead and makes sure that the matching part is not followed by what's inside.

`\b` is a word boundary and will match only between `\w` and `\W` (and vice versa).

Comment: @BenVoigt Forgot the `\b` in the first expression. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

What about looking for everything in brackets ?

```
var s = "Friday the 13th (1980)";
var result = s;
var  match = new Regex(@"\((?<date>\d+)\)").Match(s);
if (match.Success)
{
    result = s.Replace(match.Groups["date"].Value, String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: The two-step process can have false positives.  Consider `"Friday the 13th (1)"`

Comment: @Ben Voigt : Yes you are right- this should be better to match a four digit pattern @"\((?<date>\d{4})\)"

Comment: That works on the single example in the question, but it doesn't meet the stated goal in the question 'Basically I want to remove all numbers in a string except for the ones that are followed by "st", "nd", "rd", "th"'